# regex returning un expected value

Tags: javascript, regex

I expected `new RegExp('\b\w{1,7}\b', "i").test('bc4rg6')` to return true since I want to test of the string "bc4rg6" is alphanumeric and has from 1 to 7 characters. But the browser is giving false. How do I fix it so that I can test for the condition stated? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the string, because `\b` is an escape sequence that turns into the backspace character.

```js
console.log(new RegExp('\\b\\w{1,7}\\b', "i").test('bc4rg6'));
```

But if the regexp is a constant, you don't need to use `new RegExp`, just use a RegExp literal.

```js
console.log(/\b\w{1,7}\b/i.test('bc4rg6'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RegExp` function doesn't accept a string as an argument.

Instead pass a `Regular Expression` pattern with the escape slashes to indicate the start and end of the pattern.

```
new RegExp(/\b\w{1,7}\b/, "i").test('bc4rg6');
```

You can read more about the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) function at Mozilla.